# Нужна помощь новичку с MVC

Tags: mvc

В рамках mvc-модели имеется представление, состоящие из нескольких форм (форма ввода логина и пароля, главная форма, несколько форм отображающихся перед главной - там какие-нибудь настройки, раздел "о программе" и т.п.).
Так вот, есть несколько вопросов:

1. Стоит ли разделить контроллер на несколько (по одному на каждое представление) или сделать один большой, содержащий ссылки на все представления?
2. Нужно ли ядро, которое будет обеспечивать переход от одного представления к другому или указать такие методы в контроллере?
3. Если нужно, то какие функции будет обеспечивать ядро, кроме как менять visible? (ведь зачем отсоединять наблюдателей от формы, если она и так будет невидимой)
4. actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) лучше сделать в представлении и вызывать из неё методы контроллера или в самом контроллере?
5. Как в actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) узнать из какого представления пришло событие, от какого объекта и какое именно событие (наведение мыши, взятие в фокус, клик левой кнопкой, клик правой или что-то другое) ?

Comment: @Andrey759, уточните язык. Я так понимаю, это java в контексте android-приложений?

> Стоит ли разделить контроллер на несколько

Да, чем тоньше контроллер, тем лучше.

Comment: Java Swing (знаю, что swing - гадость, но не посмотреть его я не мог)

Answer (score 1):

1. MVC, оно на то и MVC чтобы облегчать жизнь программисту, вы можете создать один контроллер который обработает все, но ведь есть вы ходите на кухню, спите в спальне, моетесь в ванной. Я думаю логика понятна.
2. Опять же, простой пример, живете вы в доме(едите, спите), а работаете в офисе(сидите, ходите, печатаете).

MVC прежде все создана для удобства разработки, если вы пользуетесь данной системой, то пользуйтесь как положено.

Comment: Довольно долго размышлял, как связать рекомендации (1 и 2) ответа с конкретными пунктами 1, 2, 3, 4 и 5 в вопросе.

Кроме тривиального (хотя и несколько противоречивого) совета

      делайте как вам удобней, но только в рамках концепции MVC

ничего путного в голову не пришло.

Comment: @avp, если вы мыслите только прямо, то своим постом я указываю на то, что у всего должно быть свое место. Каждый контроллер должен выполнять конкретную задачу, а не собирать в себе все.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ на первый вопрос. В этом контексте ответ на второй вопрос становится очевидным. По поводу третьего вопроса - это скорее не вопрос, мне просто хотелось услышать побольше информации по данной теме от знающих людей. Остаются без ответа ещё четвёртый и пятый вопросы (в рамках к примеру Java Swing, хотя и не только).

Comment: Видел например такую реализацию модели наблюдатель:
JButton button1;
button1.addActionListener(this);
public actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
if(event.getSource() == button1)
... и далее вызов какого-нибудь метода из контроллера.
}
Такое сравнение за пределами класса представления я провести не смогу, т.к. button1 приватный, а передавать ссылку на него в контроллер мне кажется диким извращением.
Но а самое главное - как делать правильно?